# I need to pass a string into textview in android

Tags: java, android

I want to pass a string into textview in android, (I have made an attempt below) I just want it to take in text from text view assign it to a string the output the string in textview. any help would be great!!

```
String str;
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input); //take text assign to e1 
str = e1.getText().toString() //take text from e1 and assign it to string str
TextView str= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
// Initialize e1
EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

// Take text from e1 and assign it to str
String str = e1.getText().toString();

// Initialize out
TextView out= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

// Set text in str to EditText out
out.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [setText(CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method of TextView

```
textView.setText("Your text from edittext");
```